# count number of list objects by specific value in a list element

Tags: r, list, loops, object, element

I have a list with 1000 list objects. In any of them , I have 20 list elements var0001:var0020 (each element does not necessarily have the same length as the other ones, I mean, mylist[[]]$var0001 has length = 1, but mylist[[]]$var0012 has length = 1000).

I need a function that would allow me to count the number of list objects inside my list when their list elements var0002 = 1, for example.

I tried things just as:

```
sum(mylist[[]]$var0002 == 1)
```

didnt work.

I could get it in a very bizarre code,

```
j <- 1
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
   if(mylist[[i]]$var0002 %in% 1){
     dum[[j]] <- mylist[[i]]
     j <- j + 1
   }
}
```

so I would like to improve it, maybe without the looping... I am pretty sure there is a way to do it in about 1 or 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer with `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

## dummy data
myList <- list(list(var1 = 1, var2 = 1), list(var1 = 0, var2 = 2), list(var1 = 1, var2 = 1))

myList %>% 
     purrr::map(~ .[["var2"]] == 1) %>% 
     unlist() %>% 
     sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

The unlist function will take all of the objects in a list into a vector. Then you can use a loop or lapply to count the number of time a value occurs within in the inner list.

`sapply(1:length(mylist), function(a) sum(unlist(mylist[[a]])==1))`

This should return a vector of length 1000 that tells you how many var0001 - var0020 have the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a minimal reproducible example.
In a tidyverse style,

```r
mylist <- 
    list(
        list01= list(
            var01 = 1:3
            ,var02 = 1:5
            ,var03 = 1:7
        )
        ,list02= list(
            var01 = 1:9
            ,var02 = 1:11
            ,var03 = 1:13
        )

    )
str(mylist)
#> List of 2
#>  $ list01:List of 3
#>   ..$ var01: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   ..$ var02: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#>   ..$ var03: int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#>  $ list02:List of 3
#>   ..$ var01: int [1:9] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#>   ..$ var02: int [1:11] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ var03: int [1:13] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

library(purrr)
mylist %>% 
    transpose() %>% 
    .$var02 %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    table()
#> .
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
#>  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>